# How 'Faster Than Light' Neutrino Was Product of Loose Cable at CERN?

Tags: experimental-physics, neutrinos, faster-than-light

[A "faster than light" neutrino discovery was actually the result of a loose cable](http://newsfeed.time.com/2012/02/22/einstein-was-right-all-along-faster-than-light-neutrino-was-product-of-error/).
A fiber-optic cable in a GPS receiver at the European Center for Particle Physics ( CERN) near Geneva

Can someone show me the light here, What's Going On ?

how long was fiber-optic cable?

Comment: (-; The particles were so afraid of the loose cable that they ran away with a speed exceeding what the relativistic police allowed. When they finally were caught, the speed turned out to be slower than light, according to the rules ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's answered e.g. on page 4 of this talk:

> http://agenda.infn.it/getFile.py/access?resId=2&materialId=slides&confId=4896

An analog circuit in the experiment is activated when the light intensity in the fiber optic cable exceeds a certain threshold. Because the connection was loose, the time measured several years ago, let's say in 2008, that did *not* include the neutrino propagation was measured about 73 nanoseconds longer than it should have been. That's because the circuit was activated later than it should have been – it was waiting when the erroneously weakened light intensity in the cable exceeds the same required threshold.

When the time *including* the neutrino propagation was measured with a more properly attached fiber optic cable e.g. in 2012, they got the right timing. The time needed for the neutrino to propagate is the difference
$$ t_{\rm travel} = t_{2012} - t_{2008} $$
Because the time measured in 2008 appears with a minus sign and it was spuriously *increased* by the loose connection, the time of neutrino travel appeared spuriously *sped up* by 73 nanoseconds. To "predict" 73 nanoseconds, one would have to describe the time dependence of the light intensity going through the fiber optic cable – the intensity is surely changing for dozens of nanoseconds – and he would have to know the exact weakening of the signal due to the loose connection.

Before the correction, the neutrinos appeared to arrive $60\pm 10$ nanoseconds too early. When the fix is applied, they appear $13\pm 10$ nanoseconds later than light which is right, within the error margin.

The collaboration also fixed another error but its effect on the result was negligible.

Comment: what was speed of neutrino by the way!@

Comment: The speed of the neutrino was of course equal to the speed of light, 299,792,458 m/s, up to the relative error of $10^{-20}$ or so caused by the neutrino masses. In reality, only 5 or so significant figures of the neutrinos' speed may be measured.